# How do I open the Contacts app Swift

Tags: swift, cncontactstore

Is there a `URL` to open the contacts application from within my application? I know you can achieve this with the settings app by using the `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` constant in Swift; however, I wasn't sure if I could do the same with the Contacts app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a deep link for opening the Contacts App.

Apple is very picky when it comes to deep-linking. They have to provide one for Settings since many apps need services like Data, Location, Bluetooth, Wifi, etc.
Unfortunately they do not extend this to the Contacts App.

However if your app needs contact information then for that Apple has provided a Contacts framework to browse through your contacts within your app itself.

Read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts).

In order to add/update/delete/merge contacts directly from your app without using the Apple's Contact UI, use the `CNSaveRequest` APIs. More on that [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cnsaverequest).

Comment: Yeah, the only issue is we want users to be able to edit contact info as well which I don't think can be done through the default UI.

Comment: Ohh, the way you phrased the question led me to think you wanted to access the native contact interface.
Anyway, if you merely want to edit contact info then you can use the CNSaveRequest APIs for directly adding/updating/deleting contacts without using the native interface. Please check the latest edit to the answer.

Comment: I did want to access the native contact interface, but since there is no way to access that I was hoping there might be some APIs in the ContactsUI framework to provide a default interface for editing contacts however the Contacts UI framework looks limited to selecting contacts only so I might have to create my own interface :(

Comment: Aah, I follow you now.
Look into ContactsUI framework. It has support "...for displaying, editing, selecting, and creating contacts in your app". Check out the CNContactViewController for a native contact card.

Comment: but do you know which part of the framework I’d use? I checked the docs and all I could see is a view controller for selecting contacts and a view controller for just showing a single contact :(. I couldn’t see anything for selecting and then editing a contact.

Comment: Use the CNContactPickerViewController for selection of a contact. Once the user does that you should get a delegate callback, use this to retrieve the the selected contact and store this somewhere. Then use this contact to init the CNContactViewController. Finally set properties (like editable) as per your requirement and then present this ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you can get to opening a contact is to write them a message in IMessage. From this screen the user can press the contact icon and open the contact page for that particular contact.

You can do this by opening the url `sms://+44776382223` where the number is the number of the person that you would like to view the contact of.